# Send Message If A Message Has A Key Word. Discord Py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I wanted the bot to reply with 'hi' every time someone mentions its name in a sentence.
I wrote this but it's not working, could someone please help :)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(msg, ctx):
    if 'astro' in msg.content:
        await ctx.send('hi there!')
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIIkU.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`on_message` doesn't take a `ctx` argument:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(msg):
    if 'astro' in msg.content:
        channel = msg.channel
        await channel.send('Hi there!')
```

Comment: You can also leave it as `await msg.channel.send('Hi there!')` if you want to condense the code slightly